# Running macro to open file window in another program, need if statement that will execute when file is saved (c#)

Tags: c#

```
private void pdfButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Operation.RunMacro("ExportPDF.cs");

     if (Operation.RunMacro == )
     {
         MessageBox.Show("PDF files exported!");
         pdfLabel.Text = pdfLabel.Text + "  - DONE!";
         pdfLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
     }
     else
     {
         pdfLabel.Text = pdfLabel.Text + " WRONG!";
         pdfLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
     }
 }
```

This is my body of code, when the pdfButton is clicked, the macro will run opening up my file window. From there the user names their files and stores to a folder, how can I make the if statement execute when they store their files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method Operation.RunMacro needs to return the operation result. Then you have a condition you can test against:

```
class Operation
{

    public bool RunMarco(string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            // export logic
            ...
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

then you can do:

```
private void pdfButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    bool runMacroResult = Operation.RunMacro("ExportPDF.cs");

    if (runMacroResult)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("PDF files exported!");
        pdfLabel.Text = pdfLabel.Text + "  - DONE!";
        pdfLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
    }
    else
    {
        pdfLabel.Text = pdfLabel.Text + " WRONG!";
        pdfLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
}
```